# Mongo append to existing key ($addToSet)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema:

```
var listingSchema = new Schema({
        street          : String,
        buildingNumber  : Number,
        apartmentNumber : Number,
        UsersAndQuestions: [{
            userID: { type: String, unique: true},
            questionID: [String],
            _id : false
    }],
});
```

And I just want to update it with a new entry to `UsersAndQuestions` which will consist of a `userID` which is a `String`, and a `questionID` which is also a `String` (but needs to be inserted into an array).

I am using this `PUT` request:

```
app.put('/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber/addUserInput/:userid/:listingid/:questionid')
```

So I have all the necessary parameters in hand.

Usually, when I wanted to update a field in a schema I used this code that I wrote:

```
app.put('/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber/addUserInput/:userid/:listingid/:questionid', function (req, res) {
    console.log("adding user and question he answered to listing schema");
    var listingToUpdate = req.params.listingid;
    var idToAdd = req.params.userid;
    var questionToAdd = req.params.questionid;
    Listing.update({_id: ObjectId(listingToUpdate)},
        {$addToSet: {UsersAndQuestions: {userID: ObjectId(idToAdd), questionID: ObjectId(questionToAdd)}}}
        , function (err, listing) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem adding the user and question to the listing" + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Success adding user and question to the listing!");
                res.send("Success!");
            }
        })
});
```

This prevents *exact* duplicates of the same UsersAndQuestions entry.

**My question is:** I want that if a `userID`   **exists** then it will **append** the `questionID` to that `userID` `questionID` array. How can it be done?

Example:

What I have so far is if my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "567300e694745bfce5bf6ed2",
  "street": "Rines",
  "buildingNumber": 1,
  "apartmentNumber": 1,
  "UsersAndQuestions": [
    {
      "userID": "564b343fbc2d4310156c6bf9",
      "questionID": [
        "5661db59b0b1b91c1d63643d"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I perform a `PUT` with the same `userID`, same `listingID`, but a **different** `questionID` I get:

```
{
  "_id": "567300e694745bfce5bf6ed2",
  "street": "Rines",
  "buildingNumber": 1,
  "apartmentNumber": 1,
  "UsersAndQuestions": [
    {
      "userID": "564b343fbc2d4310156c6bf9",
      "questionID": [
        "5661db59b0b1b91c1d63643d"
      ]
    },
    {
      "userID": "564b343fbc2d4310156c6bf9",
      "questionID": [
        "5669d90a058ceddc158e97e2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And what I **want** to get is:

```
{
  "_id": "567300e694745bfce5bf6ed2",
  "street": "Rines",
  "buildingNumber": 1,
  "apartmentNumber": 1,
  "UsersAndQuestions": [
    {
      "userID": "564b343fbc2d4310156c6bf9",
      "questionID": [
        "5661db59b0b1b91c1d63643d", "5669d90a058ceddc158e97e2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the correct syntax for doing what I wish to do?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340798/mongo-addtoset-with-multiple-values-correct-syntax/34341272#34341272)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I will add the answer here.

You need to add object to set UsersAndQuestions:

```
{$addToSet: {UsersAndQuestions: { userID: idToAdd, questionID: questionToAdd } }}
```

I would do it with two queries:

```
Listing.update({_id: ObjectId(listingToUpdate), 'UsersAndQuestions.userID': idToAdd},
{"$addToSet": {"UsersAndQuestions.$.questionID": questionToAdd}}
, function (err, result) {
    if(result.n === 0){
        //we haven't found document with the userId - idToAdd
        //we need to insert to UsersAndQuestions document with this user
        Listing.update({_id: ObjectId(listingToUpdate)},
            {$addToSet: {UsersAndQuestions: { userID: idToAdd, questionID: questionToAdd } }},
            function(err, res){

            })
    }
})
```